# C++ error C2040: 'e' : 'Logger' differs in levels of indirection from 'const std::exception &'

Tags: c++, logging

I get this error:

C++ error C2040: 'e' : 'Logger' differs in levels of indirection from 'const std::exception &'

I've seen that this error usually occurs when something is declared twice but I can't see anything wrong with it. Please take a look at my attempt, as I am trying to make a logger class.

Main.cpp

```
#include "Logger.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
try
{
    string("abc").substr(10);
}
catch (const exception &e)
{
    Logger e;
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably not the best idea to use the name of the parameter same as it's type: `Logger::Logger(const exception& exception)` try `Logger::Logger(const exception& e)`.

Comment: Try renaming your Logger variable from `e` to something else.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did that before I forgot to put the updated one. It's changed now.

Comment: @Vaughn what do you mean, then I'll be taking a variable that does not exist? If you mean change the exception& variable then it does the same thing

Comment: @user3076273 `const e&`?? `e` is a type? Didn't you just wanted to write that vice versa?

Comment: I've added an answer which may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you think that you are passing `e` to the `Logger` constructor, but you are actually creating a new variable called `e`.

Instead of

```
catch (const exception &e)
{
    Logger e;
}
```

try

```
catch (const exception &e)
{
    Logger l(e);
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest how I can make a better logger class or improve on mine?

Comment: @user3076273: That would be a more appropriate question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but from what I've seen so far, you don't really need a logger class, just a function.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I used that website and they told me it's not a place to ask for improvements. I just wish to develop on the logger class.

Answer (score 1):

Here there is your double declaration, the exception `e` and `Logger` instance.

```
catch (const exception &e)
                        ^
{
    Logger e;
           ^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (const exception &e)
```

Creates a parameter named `e` that is of the type `const exception &`.  Then

```
Logger e;
```

declares another `e` of a different type in the same scope.  You need to change one of the variable names